# Is there a way to change the CSS of someone's website every time you go to the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm a little bit of a noob so I apologize if this is a dumb question but I'm wondering if there's a way to edit the CSS of a website every time you go to automatically.

Many kids in my programming class find the dark theme on their eyes to be easier. Of course our school website updates their site to a sleek all white design.

Obviously I could just inspect and then change the CSS but I'm wondering if there's a way so that the CSS I change stays or is permanent and will automatically load like what it was changed to.

Is there possibly a way you could load a javascript file automatically when a page is reloaded or something?
Is there some kind of file or program that could possibly do this? Or anyone have any ideas how I could make this possible?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: develop and addon that you install on your browser

Comment: There are browser extensions that let you do exactly this: Stylish is a very popular one. I am not sure if it is OK to link to it here, so just look up "stylish extension" online.

Comment: I would suggest addons to the browser. If you're using Firefox og Chrome, there are a number of different plugins that you can use. Most of these have the possibility to add custome styles to your website.

Comment: “user stylesheet” addons might be what you want to look up. (User stylesheets are built into at least Firefox, but they’re a bit inconvenient.)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there possibly a way you could load a javascript file automatically when a page is reloaded or something?

If you really want to go the Javascript route, yes, it's pretty easy. Install a userscript manager of your choice, such as Tampermonkey, and insert a customized `<style>`. For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Input Height
// @include     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
  textarea.wmd-input, textarea#wmd-input {
    height: 800px;
  }
`;
```

You can also change/remove style attributes directly on page load.

There are also add-ons specifically designed to customize styles, for example, [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en).

Comment: If you're going to reference the greasemonkey clone, why not use the clones `GM_addStyle` method instead - hmmm, nevermind, I see it's been removed from greasemonkey, so I guess it's best not to use it